# Arc over multiple columns in table

Tags: text-decorations, tabu

I want to have a flat arc over some columns in a table (`tabu` environment, as I am using to define independent colours for each row). Similar to the `hhline` in which bar are drawn over multiple columns.

More completely, parts of the row can have bar, double bars or arcs over some columns, and row colours should be independently specifiable.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage[dvips]{color}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabu}{c c c c c}
\hhline{~~~~~}
\rowfont{\color{red}}
x & y & z & q & w\\
\\
\rowfont{\color{blue}}
\hhline{~--~-}
a & b & c & d & e\\
\\
\rowfont{\color{magenta}}
\hhline{~~===}
l & m & n & o & p\\
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

(Arc is the only thing I could not get)

How can I achieve it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Anyone, please?

Comment: I strongly suggest you do not use `tabu`.  His author has stated that the next version to be not backwards compatible and with incompatibility issues

Comment: I picked ``tabu`` to define independent colours for each row...Is there an easier method for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This result is not automated, but it might give you some ideas

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage[dvips]{color}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabu}{c c c c c}
\hhline{~~~~~}
\rowfont{\color{red}}
x & y & z & q & w\\
\\
\rowfont{\color{blue}}
\hhline{~--~-}
a & b & c & d & e\\
\\
\rowfont{\color{magenta}}
\hhline{~~===}
l & m & n & o & p\\
\\
&&\multicolumn{3}{l}{\addvbuffer[-1ex]{$\hstretch{4}{\frown}$}}\\
\rowfont{\color{magenta}}
l & m & n & o & p\\
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

[image]