# Tikz wave not covering multiple tabular columns

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, multicolumn, decorations

This is a follow-up to my earlier questions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140789/column-with-fixed-width-and-centre-alignment) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111145/arc-over-multiple-columns-in-table). In short, what I want to achieve is an arc over multiple columns, which I am achieving using Tikz. Code is shown below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\mulcol}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\newcommand\myarc[2][]{%
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node at (0,0.4) (a) {};#2%
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node at (0,0.4) (b) {};
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,out=35,in=145,distance=0.2cm]
    \draw[#1] (a.center) to (b.center);
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{*{6}{c}}
\myarc{a&a}&a&a&a&a\\
\myarc{\mulcol{a}}&\mulcol{a}&\mulcol{a}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

**Produced output**:

[image: Output from the code above]

With this the first row gives the correct orientation of the content and the arc above, but the second row offsets the content of the multicol forward (circled red in the figure). What causes this offset to occur and is there any  way to correct it?

Comment: Your sample document produces errors (due to a well know "feature" involving `\multicolumn`); please fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment that `\multicolumn` must be the first thing in a cell. This solution switches `myarc` and `mulcol` around and add `\hfill` to fill the width.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\mulcol}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}
\newcommand{\mulcols}[1]{\multicolumn{3}{c}{#1}}  % newly added command
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}


\newcommand\myarc[2][]{%
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node at (0,0.4) (a) {};#2%
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node at (0,0.4) (b) {};
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,out=35,in=145,distance=0.2cm]
    \draw[#1] (a.center) to (b.center);
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

Case for  multicolumn 2

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{*{6}{c}}
\myarc{a&a}&a&a&a&a\\[2pt]
\mulcols{\myarc{\hfill a\hfill}}&\mulcol{a}&\mulcol{a}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: I have accepted the answer as it is the most apt for the qn I asked. However, what modification to the above solution would be needed if the same arc is to span the next `\multicolumn` as well? The scope of the arc seems to restricted to that `\multicolumn` alone in this case.

Comment: @L__ -- In my view, your `myarc` macro is limitd because the point a and b are the same point. To span to the next multicolumn, you need to redefine `myarc` -- generating two `tikzmarks` and put them inside of `\mulcol`, then connect them with arc. In short, replace `\myarc` with `\tikzmark` and then connect them via drawing arc.   Here is a reference. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170879/34618

Comment: Formed the more general and powerful macro from info in the above link that you gave. Thanks!!